# Outputfield value formula

Tags: visualforce, outputfield

can I put into a outputfield a formula like below?

IF Today - LastModifiedDate > 60 , RED ,
IF Today - LastModifiedDate > 30 , YELLOW,
ELSE GREEN

Thanks,
Sascha

```
<apex:outputField value="{IF{!AccOpp.LastModifiedDate}-{!Today}>60,'RED'I{IF{!AccOpp.LastModifiedDate}-{!Today}>30,'YELLOW','GREEN'}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The `value` attribute on an [apex:outputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputField.htm) has to be an SObject field. If you want to display text then you can use [apex:outputText](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm)

Your formula doesn't look correct. I believe it should be something like this:

```
{!IF((TODAY() - DATEVALUE(AccOpp.LastModifiedDate)) > 60, 
     "RED", 
      IF((TODAY() - DATEVALUE(AccOpp.LastModifiedDate)) > 30, 
          "YELLOW", 
          "Green"))
}
```

Comment: The LastModifiedDate needs an additional function. <apex:outputText value="{!IF((Today() - DATEVALUE(AccOpp.LastModifiedDate)) > 60, "RED", IF((Today() - DATEVALUE(AccOpp.LastModifiedDate)) > 30, "YELLOW", "GREEN"))}" /> It works, Thanks.

Comment: I tried to change the words into an image, but I get an error Function IMAGE may not be used in this type of formula. {!IF((Today() - DATEVALUE(AccOpp.LastModifiedDate)) > 60, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=/015b0000001EJIK"), IF((Today() - DATEVALUE(AccOpp.LastModifiedDate)) > 30, IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=/015b0000001EJLH"), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=/015b0000001EJJAE")))}
Any ideas?

Comment: Your field type is probably not compatible with an image, e.g. its of type `Text`. I imagine that `Text Area (Rich)` would be the only valid field type.